# setting onClick prevents button from having default behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form as follows:

```
<form>
     <RaisedButton
        label={'next'}
        onClick={this.handleNext}
        type={'submit'}
        style={{marginRight: 12}}/>
</form>
```

The problem is that when I set onClick for  a button it prevents buttons default behavior(which is submit).
Is this behavior a react expected one?  how can I work around it?

please note: I have used redux-form and material-ui `Stepper` component but since I think this is a react related problem I created a more simple code.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that the `RaisedButton` component you're importing has an `evt.preventDefault()` call that's blocking submit. To verify, replace `RaisedButton` with a normal html `button` and see if the form submits. If it does, you'll have to look at the `RaisedButton` source and see if you can stop the `preventDefault` call.

Comment: I did replace with button. Same issue.nothing changed

Comment: Ah, does the form not have a submit url? If you put an `onSubmit` listener on the `<form>` tag, does it fire?

Comment: it is like ``<form action="post" onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}`` but onSubmit doesn't fire.

Comment: `{handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}` that syntax seems odd to me. What if you just make it `onSubmit={() => {window.alert('hi')}}`?

Comment: I'm using redux-form. this is the essential setup for it.

Comment: Does your `handleNext` function return false or a falsey value?

Comment: yes I return false, but again it doesn't call the default behavior.

Comment: figured out sth, I update state in onClick. if don't update state in onClick it submits the form. is this an expected behavior?

Comment: I think returning false is your problem, it can prevent the submission of the form. What if you return true?

Comment: I tried returning true, same issue. but commenting ``setState`` submits form

Comment: Ah, can't really help more without more code examples but it seems like you figured it out kind of? `setState` in and of itself shouldn't prevent event cascading

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you forget to add a prop `type=submit`, if you want to submit form data, you should add a prop `type=submit` for your button element. RaisedButton only provide a normal button.